# Pip installation fetching irrelevant package version

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have a custom package (`app_init`) in our internal artifactory. Below are the versions available for this package,

```
app_init==0.1
app_init==0.2
app_init==0.3
.
.
.
app_init==0.10
```

I tried to install `django` & `app_init` in a single line,

```
pip install django app_init
```

The version got installed is `app_init==0.5`.

I tried to install both `django` & `app_init` in a different lines,

```
pip install django
pip install app_init
```

and it fetches the correct latest version (i.e `app_init==0.10`).

What should be the reason for this?

Comment: ```pip install django,app_init```

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: A ```,``` comma

Comment: I mean, why I'm getting specifically 0.5 when tried with space?